# How can i save multiple IMGs after page refreshing?

Tags: javascript

There is a code of localStorage, i can add multiple images and only one image left after refreshing the page. How can I put all the pictures after refreshing?

[This is the code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8V9w6/)

I also created a code snippet here:

```js
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
            
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
          localStorage.setItem('img', e.target.result);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);


  if(localStorage.img) { 

         var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML += ['<img class="thumb" src="', localStorage.img,
                            '" title="test"/>'].join('');

          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
    
    }
```

```css
  .thumb {
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
  }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the localstorage key on line:

```
localStorage.setItem('img', e.target.result);
```

You can only have unique keys in localstorage and its values must be strings. So for saving multiple image you can:

- Create a unique key for each image
- Create an array for storing the imgs and then save it into localstorage under one key using `JSON.stringify()`

I've created this helper functions to save and retrieve the imgs from localStorage. Hope it helps:

```js
function saveImgToStorage(img) {
   let imgs = localStorage.getItem('imgs');

   let imgsArray = imgs ? JSON.parse(imgs) : [];

   imgsArray.push(img);
   localStorage.setItem('imgs', JSON.stringify(imgsArray))
}

function getImgsFromStorage () {
   return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('imgs'))
}
```

Also note that since the value returned from `getImgsFromStorage()` is an array, you need to make a loop to append each image to the document